# I have an issue with respawning(reposition) same background object in cycles like in flappy bird game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this issue with re-positioning the background game objects after being hit by BackgroundRespawner game object. Btw background gameobject are moving -0.1f with each update.

So I have 6 background game objects.So when BackgroundRespawner collides with 1st background game object it should move it to 6th position. Here is the code for that

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "StartCollider") {
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(0, 3, col.transform.parent.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.z * 5 - 4.0f * col.bounds.size.z);
        col.transform.parent.position = newPosition;
    }
}
```

And this works fine they are align well after couple of cycles but after that i have issue with empty space between background game objects and i tried everything, but i have trouble fixing this issue. Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance :)

The first game object "Korito 1" should be at position "Korito 6".

[image: Here is screenshoot]

Comment: What exactly is "6th position"? Is it static or is it moving?

Comment: It is 6 place of background game object. All 6 of them goes back 
backgroundGameObjects -= 0.1f

Comment: @BrandonMiller it is moving btw.